# Cannot resolve method add() when using Fragment Manager

Tags: android

Even though I've used `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;`

I got the error like this...

> Error:(58, 42) error: no suitable method found for
>   add(int,AnnouncementListFragment)
>
> method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment,String) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>
> method FragmentTransaction.add(int,Fragment) is not applicable (actual
>   argument AnnouncementListFragment cannot be converted to Fragment by
>   method invocation conversion)
>
> method FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment,String) is not applicable
>   (actual argument int cannot be converted to Fragment by method
>   invocation conversion)

Part of my code:

```
displayFragment = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragment = new AnnouncementListFragment();
displayFragment.beginTransaction().add(R.id.announce_fragment,fragment).commit();
```

Comment: Could anyone help with this please..?

Comment: Is your `AnnouncementListFragment` extends with `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`?

Comment: make sure that you're using android.support.v4.app.Fragment for AnnouncementListFragment class.

Comment: No...I've used import android.app.Fragment;...Now its solved.Thanks guys.

Comment: Always like to help !! Wel come !

Answer (score 1):

YOu can replace one line in your code

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
```

to 
    getFragmentManager()

or you can try like this way if you are replace/add from fragment activity.

```
public void displayFragmentWithArg(Fragment mFragment) {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.addToBackStack("back");
    transaction.add(R.id.act_login_main_lContainer, mFragment).commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FragmentManager displayFragment = ((FragmentActivity)getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragment = new AnnouncementListFragment();
    displayFragment .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.announce_fragment, new fragment)
            .commit();
```